# How to log JSON to console and get cloudwatch logs pick up correct metadata?

Tags: node.js, winston, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

```
winston.info('Hello again distributed logs', { app: 'test', sid: 1 })
pino.info('Hello again distributed logs', { app: 'test', sid: 1 })
```

Output:

```
{"app":"test","sid":1,"level":"info","message":"Hello again distributed logs","timestamp":"2017-02-16T03:34:06.186Z"}
{"pid":4269,"hostname":"Macchiato.local","level":30,"time":1487216046197,"msg":"Hello again distributed logs {\"app\":\"test\",\"sid\":1}","v":1}
```

I have fluentd daemon to pickup container stdout and ship it to cloudwatch.

In the example above, cloudwatchlogs can detect the metadata correctly from [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) and I will be able to query the log like this

```
{$.app = "test"}
```

However, winston console is not working like that and everything got push to `log` attribute.

Does anyone know how to fix this. I'm using winston console with `json: true` and `stringify: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it's not an issue with `winston`.

I use `pm2` to run node and i need to pass `--raw` arg to it to get raw log.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this, there is a npm package that might help you, a drop-in replacement for console.log called [console-log-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-json).  The nice thing about it is that it will create consistent JSON formatted logs, despite the fact that you can throw at console.log() any number of parameters in any order, including other JSON objects as well as Error objects and plain strings.

It also handles automatically adding some extra helpful attributes such as time stamps and file where the console.log() was called from, etc..

Thes all get printed to STDOUT so any log shipping and aggregator can pick it up and parse the JSON.

[image: sample of JSON colorized output]